# Angular componente anidado genera un espacio innecesario

Tags: angular

Soy nuevo usando angular y no sé como formular mi pregunta espero me puedan ayudar a comprender como funciona este framework.

Tengo creado este componente llamado app-list-item el cual contiene otros componentes hijos:

```
<app-list-item>
    <app-list-avatar><i class="mdi mdi-send"></i></app-list-avatar>
        <app-list-content>
            <app-list-title>Talara</app-list-title>
            <app-list-subtitle>Ciudad</app-list-subtitle>
         </app-list-content>
  </app-list-item>
```

El problema está en que genera un 'espacio' en cada componente creado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y así con cada componente.
Espero me ayuden o tenga que reformular la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

los espacios en blanco no tienen que ver con que sean componentes separados, sino con el css que estos tengan implementados.
Probablemente estés utilizando clases propias de un framework de css como bootrstap o algún template que ya tiene clases predefinidas, por lo que vas a necesitar cambiar los estilos generales de esta para tenerlo que quieres.
Para lo cual tienes varias opciones, puedes editar los estilos globales desde styles.css, pero este cambio afectará a todos los componentes que utilicen esta clase.
También puedes hacer el cambio en el css propio de cada componente, si es que la clase está expuesta en el propio html.
Si la clase NO está expuesta en el html, entonces tendrás que modificar el css utilizando el selecto ::ng-deep. Te dejo unos documentos para que revises sobre esto :
https://angular.io/guide/component-styles